# Use specific graphics card for a task on Arch Linux

Tags: graphics-card, arch-linux

I have a laptop with two graphics cards: One of them is the integrated Intel chip, the other a dedicated Nvidia card. My question is whether there is a command like
*command* celestial
which allows me to run celestial with a specific card from the terminal.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using the open-source nouveau driver, or proprietary nvidia one?

Comment: I'm using nouveau, but i would change the driver, if the other is better / more useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the integrated card is used. To run a program on the discrete GPU when using the native driver (nouveau), use:

```
env DRI_PRIME=1 celestial
```

According to Arch Linux wiki, this should work with the most recent nvidia drivers as well.

See more details and instructions at:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA_Optimus
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bumblebee

Comment: This was what I was searching for! By times I will take a look on Bumblebee and Optimus.

Answer (score 0):

By default, all tasks will pick automatically pick the default graphic card. To run the task on a specific GPU, you need to change your graphics card settings.

Right click on your desktop and click on ‘Graphic Properties’ to open the Graphics and Media Control panel. Now, click on Advanced Mode and then Ok.

Follow the instructions as you see on your screen to select the graphics card you want to use for a specific task. Although you can also use a command to perform this task, it’s a straightforward process to do so.

Comment: You're taking about a Windows-specific tool. The OP specified Linux.