# How can I select the Nvidia GPU I want to run my program on on Arch Linux?

Tags: graphics-card, arch-linux, nvidia

I have two Nvidia GPU's aviable to my computer with Arch Linux installed. The Packages I use for the GPU are `nvidia-prime`, `optimus-manager`, `nvidia` and `nvidia-settings`. prime-manager is set to hybrid (with Intel UHD 630) and the two GPU's are a NVIDIA RTX2080TI and a NVIDIA GTX1650TI. How can I now select the GPU that I want to run a program on?

My BIOS does not support disabling devices.

**Laptop Specifications**: [Intel Core i7-10700, 32GB DDR4@3200MHz](https://clevo-computer.com/en/detail/index/sArticle/6142)

Comment: What's your **laptop model**? Could add that information to your post?

Comment: @JorgeLuiz My Laptop Model is a Clevo NK50SE, which shows up as NKx0Sx in the neofetch. The BIOS does not support disabling devices.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use specific graphics card for a task on Arch Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1300860/use-specific-graphics-card-for-a-task-on-arch-linux)

Comment: @Gantendo no, as this only allows me to select between a Intel CPU and a Nvidia GPU. I need to select between two Nvidia GPUs, but thanks for your effort.

Comment: [@lorhof1 Could you add the output of following command line to your post: cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia-drm-outputclass.conf](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA_Optimus#Use_NVIDIA_graphics_only)

Comment: @JorgeLuiz it's empty...

Comment: Firstly, you'd back up the **/etc** diretory. Could you manage to do that? Or do you already own some **backup**?

Comment: Run this command and add to your post: **lspci -k | grep -A 2 -E "(VGA|3D)**

Comment: I currently have some hardware issues. Will get back once fixed.